# Using "that" for nested subordinate clauses

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I wrote

> Suppose **that** you know **that** 10% of people are smokers.

Are using of two "that" natural?
Can I say it in other ways and omit one or two "that"s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly good, and reasonably natural.

You could omit either or both of the thats.

Omitting the first one is quite natural.

Normally, omitting the second would also be natural; but in this case it might be confusing, because of the alternative meaning of "know", as "be acquainted with", so the resulting sentence could be a "garden path" sentence (You might think it was saying "Suppose you know 20% of people ... " and have to reparse when you hit "are").

Comment: +1 for pointing out the risk of garden path parsing when you omit the second that.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose that *you know* that 10% of people are smokers. [emphasis mine]

What is atypical, if not unnatural, here, given the usual way such statements are used, is not the use of **that** but that the content of the supposition is *knowledge* of a fact rather than the fact itself.

Also, with percentages, it's typical to say **population** not **of people**.

**Suppose one in ten people is a smoker.**

or

**Let's suppose 10% of the population smoke(s).**

Comment: Yes, I took it that this was a step in an argument about knowledge and evidence, not an argument about material facts.